# How do I convert a file's line number to a byte offset (or get the byte offset of the beginning of each line with a BufferedReader)?

Tags: java, android

I'm using a FileReader wrapped in a LineNumberReader to index a large text file for speedy access later on.  Trouble is I can't seem to find a way to read a specific line number directly.  BufferedReader supports the skip() function, but I need to convert the line number to a byte offset (or index the byte offset in the first place).

I took a crack at it using RandomAccessFile, and while it worked, it was horribly slow during the initial indexing.  BufferedReader's speed is fantastic, but... well, you see the problem.

Some key info:

- The file can be any size (currently 35,000 lines)
- It's stored on Android's internal filesystem (via **getFilesDir()** to be exact)
- The formatting is **not** fixed width, unfortunately (hence the need to read by line)

Any ideas?

Comment: If the lines aren't fixed length, there's no direct way to get from a line number to a byte position without keeping track as you're reading. Unless, of course, you create an index as you read, tracking the relationship between byte position and line numbers (which is keeping track, as I mentioned).

Comment: I'm perfectly fine with tracking byte position during the initial indexing, but how do I do it?  I can't find a way to get the current offset after each readline() without using RandomAccessFile.

Comment: @wirbly Use RandomAccessFile *once* to index the file, and then open up an index file and `writeInt(pos)` each offset into the file.

Comment: @ironchefpython Unfortunately I can't use RandomAccessFile at all due to the time required.  (Indexing isn't a one-time affair)

Comment: @wirbly How does this file get onto the device in the first place?  Is it downloaded from somewhere?  Synced from a desktop?  There has got to be a way to write an index when the file is instantiated.

Comment: @ironchefpython It's downloaded over HTTP via a GZIPInputStream and written to the Android's internal filesystem via a BufferedOutputStream.

Comment: @wirbly There is your answer.  While you're writing to the BufferedOutputStream, every time you see a EOL, write the current file position to an index file.

Comment: @ironchefpython Ah, good idea.  I'm getting good results with MJB's method, but this is something I'll remember for the future.

Comment: @wirbly If you can afford to scan through the whole file counting newlines every time you want to retrieve a numbered line, that will work, but if you create an index, you only need to do it once.

Comment: @ironchefpython I'm currently writing the file with: byte[] buffer = new byte[65536]; while ((len = instream.read(buffer)) != -1) { outstream.write(buffer, 0, len); } ... Can you advise on syntax to search for EOLs in that loop?

Comment: Easy.  `int filePos = 0; BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream); byte[] buf = reader.readLine().getBytes(); indexFile.writeInt(filePos); filePos += buf.length; outstream.write(buf, 0, buf.length)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Describes an extended RandomAccessFile with buffering semantics](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip26.html)

Comment: link +1;  I think I read the linked article a year back, but was too lazy to search for it again :)

Comment: I only glanced at it briefly and it looks like it might make some EOL assumptions, so people should be careful of that.

Comment: This is definitely the dream class I was looking for.  :)  You're right about the EOL issue though, I'm getting an IOException at the end of the file.  Can you see any quick fixes?  (I'm using getNextLine() btw)

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to look more deeply at this.

Answer (score 0):

> Trouble is I can't seem to find a way to read a specific line number directly

Unless you know the length of each line you can't read it directly

There is no shortcut, you will need to read then entire file up front and calculate the offsets manualy.

I would just use a BufferedReader and then get the length of each string and add 1 (or 2?) for the EOL string.

Comment: Will file encoding have an effect on using using string.length() to get a byte count?  If so, is there a more trustworthy way to get the actual number of bytes for each readline()?

Comment: @wirbly Yes, encoding will *absolutely* have an effect on line length measured in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Consider saving an file index along with the large text file.  If this file is something you are generating, either on your server, or on the device, it should be trivial to generate an index once and distribute and/or save it along with the file.

I'd recommend an int[] where each value is the absolute offset in bytes for the n*(index+1) th line.  So you could have an array of size 35,000 with the start of each line, or an array of size 350, with the start of every 100th line.

Here's an example assuming you have an `index` file containing an raw sequence of int values:

```
public String getLineByNumber(RandomAccessFile index, 
                              RandomAccessFile data, 
                              int lineNum) {
    index.seek(lineNum*4);
    data.seek(index.readInt());
    return data.readLine();
}
```

Comment: I would but I don't have control of the original text file generation.  What I'm trying to do is index generation after the fact.  (Plus the original file isn't static, so the index must be created at runtime)

Answer (score 0):

Just wrapping up the previous comments :

Either you use `RandomAccessFile` to first count byte and second parse what you read to find lines by hand OR you use a `LineNumberReader` to first read lines by lines and count the bytes of each line of char (2 bytes in utf 16 ?) by hand.

Answer (score 0):

> I took a crack at it using
>   RandomAccessFile, and while it worked,
>   it was horribly slow during the
>   initial indexing

You've started the hard part already.  Now for the harder part.

> BufferedReader's speed is fantastic,
>   but...

Is there something in your use of RandomAccessFile that made it slower than it has to be?  How many bytes did you read at a time?  If you read one byte at a time it will be sloooooow.  IF you read in an array of bytes at a time, you can speed things up and use the byte array as a buffer.

Comment: I was using RandomAccessFile's readline() method to read each line, keeping track of the offset with getFilePointer() along the way.  Will using a byte array be faster then readline()?

Comment: @wirlby, Yes.  [readline](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#readLine%28%29), according to its documentation, reads one byte at a time until a line terminator is detected.  The answer by MJB links to exactly what you want: RAF augmented with a buffer.

Comment: Ah, that explains the speed.  I'm working on implementing MJB's method now.